# Measuring coolant flow in a radiator

Tags: coolant

My question goes like this:

suppose that I suspect that there is a clog in my cooling system that lets water through, but not enough to sufficiently cool the car.  It seems to me like the best way to troubleshoot this is with some kind of flow-rate meter that could be connected in line to a radiator hose.  But I have never known any of my mechanic friends to have such a device for automotive cooling systems, and the few that I see online seem like they're more made for engineers and tech-developers than shop-repair people.

Is there such a device and I'm just overlooking it?  Otherwise, is there some way that I'm missing that coolant flow rate can be measured?

Comment: Most of us do things like test the radiator for flow using a hose pipe.

Comment: Can you tell me more about this?

Comment: You can but the cost is prohibitive to test it with any accuracy.